# Get sum/average value of records defining equal time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, function, build

I have the following information (return by view):

```
DateTime   ItemID  UserTyp Seconds

2012-01-01 10      S       12      

2012-01-01 10      S       18  

2012-01-01 11      S       22  

2012-01-02 11      M       52  

2012-01-02 10      S       120  

2012-01-02 11      S       NULL  

2012-01-03 15      M       112  

2012-01-03 12      S       182  

2012-01-04 10      M       NULL
```

What I need to done is to calculated the sum of all seconds by user types, but for five periods.

The periods are set in the following way:

1. Get the first and the last date
2. Divided all days on five
3. The result of the division is the days that one period includes

Then for each period, depending on the DateTime and the UserType of the records, I should come up with this records:

```
Periods  UserTypeS_SUM(Seconds) UserTypeM_SUM(Seconds)
1        
2        
3
4
5
```

Also, I should check if there is at least 5 records, before the division is make - if I have 4 for example, only one period will be used.

I know it does not look so different, I have started to make a solution using function, but it looks kinda ineffective to me. Are there some build-in functions that could do this easy?

EDIT: I am really sorry but  I have forget to mention that the I should this in view or table-valued function. No store procedures are allowed in this case.

Comment: You should include your existing function and example output

Comment: @podiluska I will past the solution I am working on when it's ready. I ask this question in order to check has anyone knew other approach.

Comment: @gotqn, I have write code for a view as you required. see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
;with cte as(
select *,NTILE(5) over(order by [DateTime]) as period 
from Table1
),
type_S as( select period,SUM([Seconds]) as UserTypeS_SUM
 from cte
 where [UserTyp]='S'
 group by period),
type_M as( select period,SUM([Seconds]) as UserTypeM_SUM
 from cte
 where [UserTyp]='M'
 group by period),
 seq as (
  select 1 as sno union all
  select 2 union all
  select 3 union all
  select 4 union all
  select 5  )
 select  seq.sno as period,UserTypeS_SUM, UserTypeM_SUM
 from seq 
 left join  type_s s
 on seq.sno=s.period
 left join type_m m
 on seq.sno=m.period
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb2a6/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to work. I am starting reading about these NTILE and OVER functions and I will make some additional tests, but this is definitely the approach I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here the query:

creating data:

```
create table #t (d DateTime,   ItemID  int,  UserTyp char(1), Seconds int);
insert into #t
values     
('2012-01-01', 10,      'S',       12      ),
('2012-01-01', 10,      'S',       18  ),
('2012-01-01', 11,      'S',       22  ),
('2012-01-02', 11,      'M',       52  ),
('2012-01-02', 10,      'S',       120  ),
('2012-01-02', 11,      'S',       NULL  ),
('2012-01-03', 15,      'M',       112  ),
('2012-01-03', 12,      'S',       182  ),
('2012-01-04', 10,      'M',       NULL );

--to other users: be free to take it for your own reply
```

Query:  **Edited due @Manatherin comment**

```
;with 

one_to_five as (
   select 1 as n union all
   select 2 as n union all
   select 3 as n union all
   select 4 as n union all
   select 5 as n
),

max_min as (
  select UserTyp, max(d) as max_d, min(d) as min_d
  from #t
  group by UserTyp),

time_for_period as (
  select UserTyp, datediff( second,  min_d, max_d ) / 5.0 as elapsed_time
  from max_min),
periods as (
select o2f.n, t4p.UserTyp, 
       dateadd(second ,elapsed_time * (n - 1)  ,mm.min_d ) as beginPeriod,
       dateadd(second ,elapsed_time * (n    )  ,mm.min_d ) as endPeriod
  from time_for_period t4p
 inner join max_min mm on t4p.UserTyp = mm.UserTyp
 cross join one_to_five o2f
 )
 select n, p.UserTyp, coalesce(sum( seconds ),0)
 from periods p
 left outer join #t t
    on t.UserTyp = p.UserTyp and 
    t.d between p.beginPeriod and p.endPeriod
 group by n, p.UserTyp
 order by 2,1;
```

[Results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82782?opt.textResults=true):

```
n UserTyp     
- ------- --- 
1 M       52  
2 M       0   
3 M       112 
4 M       0   
5 M       0   
1 S       52  
2 S       0   
3 S       120 
4 S       0   
5 S       182
```

At this time you should  pivot by user.

disclaimer: I have write the query and I don't go back to see results coherence, be free to debug it.

Comment: @Manatherin, I know, but the diffuclt issue is to calculate periods and not to aggregate seconds, because this I have stop here. The last step is a single group by select.

Comment: @Manatherin, writed last query. You agree now? Do you need I pivot by user also? This is not complete code service, only a free help ...